# Managing instance lifecycle of WCF client

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

Is it OK to store a WCF client instance on a singleton to use on the whole appdomain? Also are you suppose to manage the state of the client because I see it has a Close and Open method?

Comment: Exact duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/563525/what-are-the-pitfalls-of-using-a-shared-static-wcf-proxy-client

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would not store it as a singleton. If you do and it ends up in a Faulted state, you'll have some trouble. Use it as an instance, and properly Close and Dispose of it.